# ***For any*** $f: B \to A$ with $(B \ne \emptyset)$, can a function $h:A \to B$ be constructed in such a way that $fhf = f$?

Tags: functions, set-theory

I've been stuck on this exercise for a while now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my try. I constructed $h$ as a left inverse of $f$.

> For any function $f: B \to A$ with $B \ne \emptyset$, there exists a function $h:A \to B$ such that $(i)$ $fhf = f$.

$h$ is a left inverse of $f$,

Define $hf:B \to B$,

We get $(ii)$ $hf(B) = B$,

By $(i)$, we have $fhf: B \to A$,

Following $(ii)$, $fhf(B) =f(hf(B)) = f(B) =A \implies f(hf) = fhf = f$

Comment: Let $h(b)$ be any element of the fiber $f^{-1}b$ if that is non-empty. Otherwise, its value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define the function  $h$, so your argument is not valid.

A proof of this requires the Axiom of Choice. Let $C$ be the range of $f$. For each point $y$ in $C$ pick an element $b_y$ such that $f(b_y)=y$. This is possible by Axiom of Choice. Now define $h(y)=b_y$. This defines $h$ in then range of $f$. For $y$ not on the range of $f$ define $h(y)$ to be any fixed element of $A$. I will let you verify that $f(h(f(b)))=f(b)$ for all $b \in B$.

Comment: Thank you, I still don't understand the Axiom of Choice quite well, so using it to prove this was very intimidating. This question came up on the Saunders MacLane's Algebra and strangely the Axiom of Choice wasn't really introduced until a couple of exercises after this one. Does this suggests that the question **can** be answered without the AoC?

Comment: Axiom of Choice is widely accepted in Mathematics so you can just assume that it is possible to pick an element from $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ for each $b \in B$ simultaneously. If you understand the rest of the proof that should be good enough.  @LucasLentz